# (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "START". "A" "B"

Tags: system-verilog

why this error?
I do not understand, START, A and B are declared in the sensibility list..
The code is a Program in a testbench. the design is a multipli.
START, A and B are signals of my design and I need this signals to work in the varefication.

The error jumps when I run the RTL simulation with questasim. I tried to change the assigment to blockin but is useless.

Also I tried to change the way of the declarations of my signals but nothing.

```
program estimulos(input CLOCK, RESET,input logic START,input logic signed[7:0] A, B,output logic signed[15:0] S,output logic END_MULT,

  reg [15:0] cola_targets   [$],
  reg [15:0] target,pretarget,salida_obtenida,
  reg FINAL);

//esto nos permitirÃÂ¡ utilziar el operador ## para los ciclcos de reloj

covergroup valores_X;    
  idea1A:coverpoint A;
  idea2B:coverpoint B;
endgroup;      


//declaraciones de tres objetos
  Bus busInst; //objeto de la clase para RSCG
  valores_X veamos; //objeto del covergroup

task monitor_input;
   begin
     while (1)
       begin       
         @(posedge CLOCK);
         if (START==1'b1)
           begin
             pretarget=A*B;//funcion ideal de obtencion de la multiplicaciÃ³n
            cola_targets={pretarget,cola_targets};//meto el valor deseado en la cola
           end
        end
   end
 endtask
 // defino mo
  task monitor_output;
   begin
     while (1)
       begin       
         @(posedge CLOCK);
         if (END_MULT==1'b1)
           begin
            target= cola_targets.pop_back();
             assert (salida_obtenida==target) else $error("operacion mal realizada");
           end
        end
   end
 endtask 


  initial
begin
    busInst = new;
    veamos=new;
    fork
      monitor_input;
      monitor_output;
    join_none
  while ( veamos.get_coverage()<25)
    begin
       busInst.paresA.constraint_mode(1);
        busInst.paresB.constraint_mode(1);
        busInst.imparesA.constraint_mode(0);
        busInst.imparesB.constraint_mode(0);
       $display("pruebo con paresA, paresB");
       assert (busInst.randomize()) else    $fatal("randomization failed");
        A<= busInst.A;  
        B<= busInst.B;
        veamos.sample();
            @(posedge CLOCK);
       START <= 1;
        @(posedge CLOCK);
       START <= 0;
      @(negedge END_MULT);
   end
   $stop;
end
endprogram
```

Comment: START, A, B are `input`s. you are trying to modify then.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because `START`, `A` and `B` are *nets*. (See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179282/driving-module-input) ). It is illegal to drive a net from an `initial` (or `always` block). But why are you driving inputs anyway?